# jQuery/CSS script change button color based on time of day

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a a href button that I need to hide depending on the time of day or changed the background color like this:

```
<a class="button not-active " href="updateScheduleRequest.php?slotid=4&amp;timeremain=120&amp;current_date=2015-08-28&amp;empnum=107">Assign Slot 4</a>
```

My CSS is configured as:

```
.button {
}
/* daytime  */
.day
{
    background-color:#e0d0b7 !important;
}
/* Sunset  */
.sunset
{
    background-color:#887f70 !important;
}
/* Nightime  */
.night
{
    display:hidden !important;
}
```

And then my jQuery is broken out to handle the time of day like this but it is not making any changes to the button at all?  What am I missing?

```
// Change background depending on user's time
function applyclass()
{
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
if (n > 19)
// If time is 7PM or later apply night theme to 'body'
$('button').addClass('night');
else if (n > 16 && n < 19)
// If time is between 4PM – 7PM sunset theme to 'body'
$('button').addClass('sunset');
else
// Else use 'day' theme
$('button').addClass('day');
}
window.onload = applyclass;
```

Comment: `$('button')` means a `<button>` element, if you mean an element with a `button` class you need to do: `$('.button')`.

Comment: Yeah, the jQuery selector is incorrect as already mentioned above

Comment: Your code is such that at midnight, the day class will be used (0 is less than 19). The reason it's not working is as spencer W says

Comment: $('.button') since you are looking for a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider using a switch statement instead of if/else if/else. It tidies up the code a bit:

```
function applyclass() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getHours();
    switch(true) {
        case (n > 19) :
            buttonClass = 'night';
            break;
        case (n > 16 && n < 19) :
            buttonClass = 'sunset';
            break;
        default:
            buttonClass = 'day';
    }
    $('.button').addClass(buttonClass);
}
```

Also, consider styling the .button element with default styles (like those in the 'day' class) and then only apply an additional class when necessary to override those styles. It's simpler than relying on a modifier class for each and every case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i am trying to use the above to swap the poster of a html5 video but does not seem to work
function posterImageTime() {
   var d = new Date();
   var n = d.getHours();
   switch(true) {
    case (n > 19) :
     //Night
     posterImage = '/night-1920.jpg';
     break;
    case (n > 16 && n < 19) :
     //Sunset
     posterImage = 'sunset-1920.jpg';
     break;
    default:
     //Day
     posterImage = 'day-1920.jpg';
   }
   //document.getElementById("videoPlayer").poster = posterImage;
   $('#videoPlayer').attr('poster' , posterImage)
  }